Flutter works on UI but having issues in the debug console
In my app, I stream from the Firebase database with a ListView.Builder and return a Row widget. In the Row widget, I have an Expanded widget at the end which has a Text widget as a child. In the Text Widget, there is one word, but the length of the word depends on the length of the field in the database.
At first, I just called the Text widget with the data and it worked well, but when the length of the field is long, the rest of the word moves to the next line, which I don't want. And also the debug console does not return any error.
So I decided to wrap the Text field with a FittedBox widget. This works well on the device UI (everything shows well)but the debug console shows several errors such as
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#07f22 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2164 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Null check operator used on a null value,
And these errors directs me to the ListView.Builder.
MY CODE
StreamBuilder
...
final request = snapshot.data!.docs;
return ListView.Builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
    builder: (context, index){
          final currentRequest = request[index];
          final status = currentRequest.get("Status");

         return Row(
          children: [
           .....//other children,
           Expanded(
             child: Column(
              children:[
              
             FittedBox(
                 fit: BoxFit.contain, //I also used BoxFit.fitWidth
                 child: Text(
                        status,
                    ),
             .....//the rest of the children
           ]
        )
      )

    ]
  );
 }
)

How can I resolve the debug issue?

If you want your text to take single line despite having a long string then you can add some styling to your text widget like so
Text(
    'This is a long text that will be truncated with an ellipsis if it exceeds one line',
    maxLines: 1,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
)

maxLines makes the Text widget to only use 1 line for text, then to hide the overflow we can set TextOverflow.ellipsis, this will truncate it like "This is a long lin..."
You can remove the FittedBox as it won;t be needed.

Well, this is not exactly what I want but it's better. Thanks
